# bash script to organize files and cleanup files

Tags: bash

I have been working on a bash script for a while now to organize my movie files.  I can do it by hand, but at the time I was taking a bash scripting class and thought I would like to use it to create this project.  I don't know if there is a better way of doing it or not, but I would like you to take a look at my script and give me feedback on it.  I believe it works, but I haven't put it through the paces yet.

```
#!/bin/bash

MovieList="points to .txt file with name of files"
DirList="points to a .txt file with the name to use to create the directory"
dest_Dir="where to put the files "
src_Dir="where to look for the files"
CreateLogFile="log file of directory created"
MoveLogFile="log file of move files"

# Will read in a list of movies and make the directories for them

createDirectory()
{
    while read -r line
    do
    if [ ! -d $dest_Dir"$line" ]
    then
            mkdir -v $dest_Dir"$line" >> $CreateLogFile
    else
            :
    fi
done < "$DirList"
}
# end createDirectory

# After directories have been created will go and find those movies and move
# them to their proper directory

movieMovies()
{
    while read -r line
do
    find $src_Dir  -type f \( -iname "$line" ! -iname ".*" \) | xargs -I '{}' mv -v {} $dest_Dir"$line" >> $MoveLogFile
done < "$MovieList"
}
# end of moveMovies

# Time to tidy up by going back and seeing if there is any empty directory
# and if so removing said directory

DirectoryEmpty()
{
while read -r line
do
    if [ $(ls -A $dest_Dir"$line" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
    then
        rmdir $dest_Dir"$line" 
    else
        :
    fi
done < "$DirList"
}
# end of DirectoryEmpty

# ---------------------------------Main---------------------------------------
createDirectory
moveMovies
DirectoryEmpty
# ----------------------------------End---------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you don’t know of a problem, try [CodeReview.SE] instead.

Answer (score 1):

#### errors

- typo: function named `movieMovie`, invoked as `moveMovie`

#### potential errors

1. use of `$dest_Dir"$line"`

   - you expect dest_Dir to end with a slash, but that's not validated anywhere
   - use `"$dest_Dir/$line"` instead (it's OK to have multiple slashes)
2. [don't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to verify the presence/absence of files:

   ```
   removeEmptyDirectory() {
       dir="$1"
       shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
       files=("$dir"/*)  # an array holding all the filenames
       if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
           # the directory is empty
           rmdir "$dir"
       else
           echo "warning: directory not empty: $dir" >&2
       fi
   }
   ```

   Even better, use `find`:

   ```
   removeEmptyDirectories() {
       while read -r line; do
           find "$dest_Dir/$line" -depth 0 -empty -exec rmdir '{}' \;
       done < "$DirList"
   }
   ```
3. Double quote all your variables, everywhere, unless you have a specific reason not to.

#### style

1. clean up your indentation.  It is idiomatic to put `then` and `do` at the end of the same line as `if` and `while` (see `removeEmptyDirectories()` example above).
2. use a consistent naming convention

   - variables `DirList`, `src_Dir` -- use camelcase or underscores, but both?
3. don't need the `else :` branch
4. "line" is not a descriptive variable name.
5. use `find -exec` instead of piping to `xargs`.